# Chrome renders unexpected value when Firefox works fine

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, vue.js

I'm rendering data in a bootstrap vue table. All is OK in firefox, but KO in chrome. 
I render myObject.data.name if it exists, else I render myObject.name

When myObject.data.name exists, it's fine both in Chrome and firefox, but when myObject.data.name is undefined, when it should print myObject.name, Chrome renders a date instead of the string I want him to render, and firefox renders it correctly. I log the data I need to check in the dev console, and the data is here so I don't know why Chrome won't render it like firefox.

I wonder if someone already had this kind of issue in a basic string property rendering

Thanks.

Comment: Hey.. "if( myObject.data.name && typeof( myObject.data.name) !=undefined) " are you checking like this? I think it should work for both. if not please share the piece of code .

Comment: I found the problem...  moment.js library was the issue. I was doing moment(mydata).isValid() before rendering, I had to change it to moment(mydata, "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ", true).isValid()

Comment: cool.. its great